# How to find time difference in minutes in SQL in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is a brief and simplified extract of my current dataset:

[image]

All my users currently have a start time and end time for various actions they complete. My time stamps are down to the milisecond. I however just want the time difference in minutes (not down to the milisecond).

Any idea how to achieve this in SQL in Snowflake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the DATEDIFF function: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html

For instance, the following returns **15**.

```
SELECT DateDiff(minute, '2021-01-01 17:08:27.890'::timestamp, 
                        '2021-01-01 17:23:23.990'::timestamp) 
               AS diff_minutes;
```